# When using "gzip --decompress", the result is "gzip: MYFILE.zip: unknown suffix -- ignored" on Windows

Tags: shell, gzip, gnuwin32

In Windows PowerShell (if it matters), I would like to decompress a zip file with `gzip` with the argument `--decompress`, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Please look at the screenshot below.

```
gzip --decompress "colorbox.zip"
```

its result:

> gzip: colorbox.zip: unknown suffix -- ignored

[image: gzip --decompress colorbox.zip ---- gzip: colorbox.zip: unknown suffix -- ignored]

Do you have any ideas how to get rid of this error? (I have to use it, because I'm using [Drush](http://drush.ws/), which [uses it](http://api.drush.ws/api/drush/includes!drush.inc/function/drush_tarball_extract/5.x).)
By the way, I have [GnuWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/getgnuwin32/) installed.

---

Another screenshot, just to make it clear it was caused by Drush 7.x-5.4:

[image: gzip --decompress when using drush colorbox-plugin]

After upgrading to 7.x-5.8:

[image: unzip after upgrading to 7.x-5.8, drush colorbox-plugin]

in PowerShell, unzip works:

[image: drush colorbox-plugin in PowerShell already works]

So with the [help of **Jeff**](https://superuser.com/a/544175/62130), I realized that something's wrong with the MIME-type detection in Drush 7.x-5.4. **Solved.** Thanks, Jeff!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You may be using the wrong tool.

`gzip` is file compressor/decompressor for files that generally have the file extension `.gz` and cannot extract files from a file like `colorbox.zip`.  On linux you would use `zip` and `unzip` to add and extract files in a zip file.  Maybe `gnuwin32` has the same zip/unzip programs?

Comment: wow, you were right, thank you very much! It seems like somehow Drush made a mistake when detecting the file's MIME type, look at this one: http://i.imgur.com/PAfJlGA.png. It tries to uncompress the zip file with gzip. I had Drush **7.x-5.4** installed, after upgrading to **7.x-5.8**, it tries to **`unzip`** the file and doesn't use `gzip` anymore: http://i.imgur.com/Faycbfp.png, it says *"Mime type for colorbox.zip is application/zip"*, much better. It was a regular command prompt, **`unzip`** is only available in PowerShell - and SUCCESS!! http://i.imgur.com/fxL9OKu.png Thanks, accepted! ;)